# "A WebService annotation is not present on class: java.net.URL" client generated from NetBeans 7.1.2 in apache-tomcat-7.0.25

Tags: web-services, netbeans, tomcat7

The war file is generated in netbeans - jdk 1.6 and then deployed in tomcat. When  I try to connect to the webservice fails with the exception below. Am I missing some class in the classpath? Appreciate any help

```
A WebService annotation is not present on class: java.net.URL
        at com.sun.xml.ws.modeler.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModele
r.java:218)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.ServiceContextBuilder.processAnnotations(Servic
eContextBuilder.java:169)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.ServiceContextBuilder.build(ServiceContextBuild
er.java:82)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java
:117)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.ja
va:50)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
        at com.oracle.xmlns.cecityapplication_jws.providervalidation_01.bpelprov
idervalidation.ProviderValidation.<init>(ProviderValidation.java:42)
        at com.main.servlet.BiotechnicsServlet.process(BiotechnicsServlet.java:2
05)
        at com.main.servlet.BiotechnicsServlet.processRequest(BiotechnicsServlet
.java:88)
        at com.main.servlet.BiotechnicsServlet.doPost(BiotechnicsServlet.java:16
2)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```